# How to use multiprocessing in geo pandas and intersection procedures by dividing the database in parts?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, geopandas

I use the following code in a MAC OS with 8 cores. But when the procedure is running I see that Python uses only one core. How I could divide the land use database in e.g. 6 parts and run intersections in each core separately? And then combine the results?

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start_time = time.time()

# Set the paths
grid_file_pattern = "emiss*.shp"
output_path = "/outpath/"
land_use_path = "/pathlu/"

def process_land_use(selected_snp, land_use_category):
    # Read the gridded emissions density file
    grid_density_file = os.path.join(output_path, f"emiss_{selected_snp}_density.shp")
    gdf_density = gpd.read_file(grid_density_file)

    # Read land use shapefile and set the CRS if not already set
    land_use_file = f"lu_ll_{land_use_category}.shp"
    gdf_land_use = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(land_use_path, land_use_file))

    # Check if CRS is defined, if not, set it to the appropriate value
    if gdf_land_use.crs is None:
        gdf_land_use.crs = "EPSG:4326"

    # Reproject to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
    gdf_land_use = gdf_land_use.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

    # Perform spatial intersection
    intersection = gpd.overlay(gdf_density, gdf_land_use, how='intersection')

    # Calculate emissions in each land use category
    for pollutant in ["CO", "NH3", "NMVOC", "NOx", "SO2", "PMc", "PM2_5"]:
        intersection[f"{pollutant}_emissions"] = intersection[f"{pollutant}_m2"] * intersection["area"]

    # Save the result
    output_file = os.path.join(output_path, f"{selected_snp}_{land_use_category}_emissions.shp")
    intersection.to_file(output_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    # Distribute gridded emissions over land use for specific SNPs
    snp_distributions = {
        "SNP1": "ind",
    }

    with Pool(8) as pool:
        pool.starmap(process_land_use, snp_distributions.items())

    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Execution completed in {elapsed_time / 60:.2f} minutes.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not multiprocessing related, but an easy performance improvement: if you use the optional `engine="pyogrio", use_arrow=True` keywords for `gpd.read_file` and `engine="pyogrio"` for `to_file`, reading and writing the files will be a lot faster.

If your input files are large and if calculating the intersection is the bottleneck, you could check out [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io). This is a library that specializes in speeding up processing of large files and it will use all CPU's by default. For some operations it uses geopandas under the hood, but not for overlays to avoid (too) high memory requirements for large files.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of geofileops.

Generic code sample for running [geofileops.intersection](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.intersection.html#geofileops.intersection):

```
import geofileops as gfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Shapefile is supported, but .gpkg will be faster
    input1_path = "input1.gpkg"
    input2_path = "input2.gpkg"
    output_path = "output.gpkg"

    gfo.intersection(
        input1_path=input1_path, input2_path=input2_path, output_path=output_path
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it on your code, but the general procedure is:

1. split the dataframe in N parts
2. make a function encapsulating the logic, the easyest way is to thing about a function to be applied for each row
3. apply the function in a Pool, each worker will take your function and one of the N parts as input
4. merge the results as needed

Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocess as mp #I am using multiprocess instead of miltiprocessing else the lambda function will not be pickled

#toy DataFrame
df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
print(df.head())
print(len(df))

#split the DataFrame in 6 parts
dataframes = np.array_split(df, 6)
print(dataframes[0])
print(len(dataframes[0]))

#define a function working for each row of the DataFrame
def my_func(row):
    return (row['A'] + row['B'])

#apply your function for each DataFrame part
with mp.Pool(6) as p:
    results = p.map(lambda x: x.apply(my_func, axis=1), dataframes)
print(results[0])
print(len(results[0]))

#concatenate the results in a Series
rs = pd.concat(results)
rs.name = 'E' #add the column name to the Series

#merge with the original DataFrame
new_df = df.merge(rs, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(new_df.head())
print(len(new_df))
```

Which gives:

```
                   A         B         C         D
8bgLdnxoB1  0.584926 -2.014131  0.489031 -0.292813
CmuOVm1MjG  1.053114 -0.089091  0.217128  0.082446
LpuOkURCkH -1.515393  2.304200  1.156891  1.070891
auazyVRu4b  0.850719  0.518987 -1.569779 -0.022444
cpXzPCGviG  0.742516 -1.085025  0.029679  0.026730
30
                   A         B         C         D
8bgLdnxoB1  0.584926 -2.014131  0.489031 -0.292813
CmuOVm1MjG  1.053114 -0.089091  0.217128  0.082446
LpuOkURCkH -1.515393  2.304200  1.156891  1.070891
auazyVRu4b  0.850719  0.518987 -1.569779 -0.022444
cpXzPCGviG  0.742516 -1.085025  0.029679  0.026730
5

8bgLdnxoB1   -1.429204
CmuOVm1MjG    0.964023
LpuOkURCkH    0.788807
auazyVRu4b    1.369706
cpXzPCGviG   -0.342509
dtype: float64
5
                   A         B         C         D         E
8bgLdnxoB1  0.584926 -2.014131  0.489031 -0.292813 -1.429204
CmuOVm1MjG  1.053114 -0.089091  0.217128  0.082446  0.964023
LpuOkURCkH -1.515393  2.304200  1.156891  1.070891  0.788807
auazyVRu4b  0.850719  0.518987 -1.569779 -0.022444  1.369706
cpXzPCGviG  0.742516 -1.085025  0.029679  0.026730 -0.342509
30
```